# Аналог textarea, только с картинками

Tags: html, php, textarea

Привет.

Хочу сделать страницу, где пользователь может писать текст и вставлять фотки (в одном поле). Насколько я знаю, textarea не поддерживает вставку картинок.

`div contenteditable="true"` не подходит, так как редактирование текста ужасно кривое получается, каретка скачет непредсказуемо.

Есть какие-нибудь еще аналоги textarea? Или лучше реализовать редактирование не единым полем, а поочередно: textarea, img, textarea, img?

Comment: Чаще всего в в визуальных редакторах textarea скрывается, а на её место вставляется div, в котором все и происходит. А потом на выходе html вставляется в textarea.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно вставлять картинки прямо в текст, то, например, [tinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php) + [Cyber Image Manager](http://cyberapp.ru/cyber-image-manager/), если нужно вставлять не URL картинок, а загружать их со своей машины. Впрочем, плагинов для загрузки картинок в tinyMCE несколько, один уже подключён в первом примере.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/e3ENM/

---

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <title>xxx</title>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="txt" placeholder="Ваше сообщение здесь!"></textarea>
    <span onClick="addImage('http://hashcode.ru/upfiles/logo.png');">Add image</span>
    <script>
        // Допустим, что нам известен id нужного тега textarea
        var Textarea = document.getElementById("txt");
        var Container = document.createElement("DIV");

        // Добавим контейнер к родителю текстарии, потом перенесем ее внутрь контейнера и скроем
        Textarea.parentNode.insertBefore(Container, Textarea);
        Container.appendChild(Textarea);
        Textarea.style.display = 'none';

        // Создадим фрейм и добавим его в контейнер редактора
        var iframe = "<iframe id='txt-frame' class='textarea' 'src=\"javascript: document.open(); document.domain='" + document.domain + "'; document.close();\" frameborder='0'></iframe>";

        Container.innerHTML = iframe + Container.innerHTML;
        var Frame = Container.childNodes[0];

        // Хитрое определение IE ;)
        var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/
            false;

        // Выделим документ фрейма в отдельную переменную
        var FrameDoc = isIE ? Frame.contentWindow.document : Frame.contentDocument;

        FrameDoc.open();

        // Если содержимое тега body будет пустым, в FF курсор станет каким-то через-чур маленьким.
        // Чтобы этого избежать, добавим & nbsp;
        FrameDoc.write('<html><head><style>body{ margin:0; padding:8px; width:394px; word-wrap:break-word; }</style></head><body>' + Textarea.value + '&nbsp;</body></html>');
        FrameDoc.close();
        FrameDoc.designMode = "on";

        Frame.contentWindow.focus();

        function addImage(src) {
            // Если в IE не установить фокус на окне редактируемого фрейма,
            // то в дальнейшем он может вставить код наверх вашей страницы, а не во фрейм ;)
            Frame.contentWindow.focus();
            var SelectionRange = isIE ? FrameDoc.selection.createRange() : Frame.contentWindow.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);

            var html = "<img src='" + src + "'/>";

            if (isIE) {
                // тут все просто
                SelectionRange.pasteHTML(html);
            } else {
                // для остальных используем вспомогательный тег
                SelectionRange.deleteContents();
                var el = document.createElement("SPAN");
                FrameDoc.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].appendChild(el);

                // Firefox не поймет, если вы сразу замените outerHTML. В версиях ниже 3-ей такое свойство вообще у него отсутствует.
                el.innerHTML = html;
                SelectionRange.insertNode(el);
                el.outerHTML = html;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>​
```

-

```
.textarea {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
    height: 120px;
    width: 100%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
textarea {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
}
span {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```